# AngularJS show only filtered elements on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a simple ng-repeat with a simple search filter.

My question is how can i show elements of this list only if filter is set ??

**I want the list be empty when the search input contains no value !!**

I can't get it work, all the items are displayed if search is filter.

Here the html :

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" data-ng-model="search" />

<div data-ng-repeat="departement in departements | filter:search">
</div>
```

Here departements objects !

```
$scope.depatements = [
    {"codeDept": "01", "libelleDept": "D1", "libelleRegion":"R1", "codeRegion": "04"},
    {"codeDept": "02", "libelleDept": "D2", "libelleRegion":"R2", "codeRegion": "08"},
    {"codeDept": "03", "libelleDept": "D3", "libelleRegion":"R3", "codeRegion":"09"}
];
```

Really thx to you guys.

Comment: `filter:search` show us search object

Comment: Done you have the search object

Comment: show how `departments` array looks like

Comment: Done guys ... Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a functional as in this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eNHrDSn0tfhJT2xJkVRC?p=preview

Comment: Oh god so simple u rocks thx !! Why i don't think about this simple ng-if ;) Thx !